# JavaScript - Replace the value between the first square brackets in a name attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, attributes

I got inputs with names like this:

```
<input class="serialize" name="day[0][0]" />
<input class="serialize" name="event[0][0][0][0]" />
```

What I want to do is to replace the character in the first clamp (day[**0**][0], event[**0**][0][0][0]) ... But the characters in the clamps may change ...

Here is a first code draft

```
jQuery( this ).find( '.serialize' ).each( function( index ) {

    var attr = jQuery( this ).attr( 'name' );
    attr = attr.replace( 'regex magic' ); // This line is the problem
    jQuery( this ).attr( 'name', attr );

} );
```

Comment: Because the array keys may change ... this will break the replace

Comment: Do you need to replace only the first character after the first `[`, or can it be multiple characters until the closing `]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) accepts a function, so you don't need to manually iterate over each element, retrieve the `name` attribute and update it.

You can just pass a function and return the replaced attribute:

```
$('.serialize').attr('name', function () {
  return this.name.replace(/^(\w+)\[.*?\]/, '$1[20]');
});
```

The expression `/^(\w+)\[.*?\]/` will select the first set of brackets after one or more `\w` characters (which are then captured and then replaced).

Which would return:

```
<input class="serialize" name="day[20][0]">
<input class="serialize" name="event[20][0][0][0]">
```

As a side note, `\w+` will match one or more of the following characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If the characters differ, you may want to use:

```
$('.serialize').attr('name', function () {
  return this.name.replace(/^(.*?)\[.*?\]/, '$1[20]');
});
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to update the value in the first set of brackets based on the index, you could use:

```
$('.serialize').attr('name', function (i) {
  return this.name.replace(/^(\w+)\[.*?\]/, '$1[' + i + ']');
});
```

Which would return:

```
<input class="serialize" name="day[0][0]">
<input class="serialize" name="event[1][0][0][0]">
<input class="serialize" name="somethingelse[2][0][0][0]">
```

Comment: But this will also remove the name of the array: `"proof[0][0]".replace(/^\w+\[.*?\]/, "[20]")` will output `[20][0]`!

Comment: Man what a elegant solution. You are a ninja ;)